# sql : How can I increment an id for every new row added?

Tags: python, sql

I want to provide an id (unique) to every new row added to my sql database without explicitly asking the user. I was thinking about using `bigint` and incrementing value for every row added compared to the id of the previous row.

Example :

```
name   id
xyz     1
```

now for another data to be added to this table, say name = 'abc', i want the id to automatically increment to 2 and then save all looking like

```
name   id
xyz     1
abc     2
```

Is there any way I can do so? Or any other data type that can increment with each new row?

P.S. I am using sql on python so I can access the last row and then add 1 to it through `fetchall()` query but that doesn't seem like the efficient way to do it.

Comment: Hi, you should specify your Databse Engine (MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL)? Add correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try identity in sql. which auto increments and is unique
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

query:-

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Age int,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

if it is already existing table

```
ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please - move most important parts of link to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a column name id in your table like

```
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Then use this method

```
previousid=SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
primarykey=PK('cu',previousid);
print primarykey; //this will print a key like CU-18-000005

function PK(keycode,last_id)
{
    seq=str_pad(last_id, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return strtoupper(keycode).'-'.date('y').'-'.seq;
}
```